# Save matplotlib plot with legend on the right in predefined width/height ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to save a matplotlib figure as a png file with a width/height ratio of 1.25. I specified this ratio via the figsize argument. But when I save the figure using the option `bbox_inches = "tight"` then the output png has a size of 553 to 396 pixels which is a ratio of 1.39. I would like to keep the `bbox_inches = "tight"` option to prevent unnecessary white space in the figure borders. I tried different approaches suggested in similar posts on stackoverflow but couldn't figure out a solution.

Here is example code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (3, 2.4), dpi = 150)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in range(3):
    ax.plot(np.random.random(10), np.random.random(10), "o", label = i)
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0.6), title = "Title")
plt.ylabel("Label")
plt.xlabel("Label")
plt.title("Title", loc = "left")
plt.savefig("test.png", format = "png", dpi = 150, bbox_inches = "tight")
```

This is the output png
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bbox_inches = "tight"` explicitely tells matplotlib to crop or expand the figure; any settings for the figure size will hence be lost. Thus you cannot use this option if you want to have control over the figure size.

Other options you have:

#### Define BBox

- Define your own `bbox_inches`, which does have the desired aspect. The dimensions of the [Bbox](http://matplotlib.org/devel/transformations.html#matplotlib.transforms.Bbox) would be `[[x0,y0],[x1,y1]]`.

  ```
  import matplotlib.transforms
  bbox = matplotlib.transforms.Bbox([[-0.2, -0.36], [3.45, 2.56]])
  plt.savefig("test.png", format = "png", dpi = 150,bbox_inches =bbox)
  ```

  [image]
  This image is now  547 x 438 pixels, thus having an aspect of 1.2488, which is as close as you can get to 1.25.

#### Adjust padding

- Use the original figure size of `(3, 2.4)` and adjust the padding, such all elements fit into the figure. This would be done using `fig.subplots_adjust()`.

  ```
  fig = plt.figure(figsize = (3, 2.4), dpi = 150)
  fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.89,
                      bottom=0.195,
                      left=0.21,
                      right=0.76)
  ```

  [image]
  This image now has the expected size of `(3, 2.4)*150 = 450 x 360` pixels.
- For an automatic determination of the subplot parameters, also look at this question: [Creating figure with exact size and no padding (and legend outside the axes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994338/creating-figure-with-exact-size-and-no-padding-and-legend-outside-the-axes)

In general, I would recommend reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317) to "How to put the legend out of the plot`.