# How to always include the full legend/ extra artists in the interactive matplotlib window

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10101700/moving-matplotlib-legend-outside-of-the-axis-makes-it-cutoff-by-the-figure-box) post, because my plots keep cutting off the legend in the interactive matplotlib window. The solution for saving figures using `plt.savefig(bbox_extra_artists=(legend,))` to include additional artists outside the axes works great, but the open window seems to follow a different set of rules. My question is, if there's a way to do the same for the interactive window, because the solution in the post above didn't work for me and just using `fig.canvas._tkcanvas.master.geometry(ipythonWindowSize)` streches the plot to the new canvas size. Is there no straighforward way to just provide the legend of a plot to the `plt.show()` call like for `plt.savefig()` so it doesn't get cut off in the interactive window? The only other way I could think of is to make a `gridspec` and display the legend in it's own seperate axes.

I don't use any `plt.subplots_adjust()` calls in my script, I just set the `figsize` when creating the figure using `plt.subplots()`.

My code is pretty long and complex so I hope the references to the post above and a screenshot will suffice to explain what the issue is.[image: The draggable legend gets cut off from in the open window]

Comment: Check [how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43439132/4124317). If you want to stick with your current font size, you obviously will *need* to make the figure wider. `.subplots_adjust()` can be used to gain more space for the legend, such that it will not be cropped.

Comment: Can I determine the value I need to provide to ```.subplots_adjust()``` based on the legend's size so I can do ```.subplots_adjust(top=val)```?

Comment: Possible options: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47540409/4124317), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272871/4124317), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43001737/4124317)